# Underlying type in an empty Observable Collection

Tags: c#

How to get the underlying type of an Observable collection using reflection?

Consider following classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Orders : ObservableCollection<Order>
{

}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method. Supposing you have an instance of `Orders`:

```
var orders = new Orders();
var type = orders.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```